# Remove already created instances in Fredhopper - Linux

Tags: 2013, fredhopper, linux

I just want to remove the instance which have been created but later on i get the error in one step. 
I have tried the below command to stop and remove the instance but not getting success.
`bin\instance <INSTANCE> stop`
`bin\deployment-agent-client remove <INSTANCE>`

I have tried there commands with root user as well as with fredhopper user. But linux is not recognizing the command.
I have tried by deleting the instances by rm command but it only deletes the directory not the complete instance.

Is there any other way to remove these instances?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could post that as an actual answer, Raimond? I'm pretty sure that's the only problem as that is the correct command - just have to use forward-slashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Linux the slashes have to be the other way around. In the root of your Fredhopper installation, type:

> ./bin/deployment-agent-client remove INSTANCE_NAME

Be sure to stop the instance before that, using the same path separator.